# How can I uninstall web apps? Specifically - google docs that got installed without my knowledge or consent

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome, webapps

I noticed that after I created a new Chrome profile, I got several web apps installed without me knowing they were installed.

Visiting them doesn't show anything the URL that opens related to web apps, image for how they appear:

[image: screenshot of how they look]

How can I remove them and prevent them from being installed again?

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and Chrome Version 116.0.5845.179 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, they get installed as a part of a new Chrome profile.

You can open the webpage `chrome://apps`, and right click on each webapp icon to uninstall it.